# netbeans 6.8: how can i add more server types ? (red5)

Tags: netbeans, red5

In netbeans 6.8 under Services -> Servers I'm able to add specific kind of servers. is it possible to add more servers to the list? and if so how? i want to be able to add red5 server to the list. i don't even mind learning to write netbeans plugins if this is what i need to resolve the issue.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there is no way to add red5 to the servers list in tomcat.
This does not impact the developer in any way besides that he will need to manually start red5 server and manually deploy the compiled application webapps directory of red5.

red5 projects can be loaded using a free-from project.

example at the following url:

http://blogs.oracle.com/coreqa/entry/setting_up_freeform_project_correctly

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be no easy way around this but I found a workaround that works for only me.
Here is it:

**CODE**

I created a file named `k.bat` and saved this code in it

```
copy "C:\location_to_my_project\dist\kilonsele.jar" "C:\location_to_red5\WEB-INF\lib\kilonsele.jar"

wrapper.exe -p "C:\Program Files (x86)\Red5\conf\wrapper.conf"

startred5-nt.bat
```

So after clicking compile in netbeans, I save time by just hitting the `k.bat`. I have created a shortcut to it on my taskbar.

**EXPLICATIONS**

- line 1 copies the compiled jar to my red5 directory
- line 2 shuts down red5
- line 3 starts it.

**DISCUSSION**

*Why don't I just put stopred5-nt.bat on line 2 ?*

Well I figured out that while red5 is waiting to shutdown, the third line runs in the background. So when shutdown it complete, there turns out there is no more thing to do so the execution stops.

There is also this sweet thing I added, since I like human readable errors. I created a method that saves text to file in my project. I only need to do something like this:

```
try {

} except {
   write2file("I can't connect to DB");
}
```

That saves the file to my red5 directory so I just created a shortcut to it in my taskbar also.

So it's fun and fast working with red5.